# How can I add data to each item in listview?

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm novice. I want to build an app where a user will scroll through Listview items, select and click that item and reads information in that item. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should use RecyclerView and Adapter in android. it's very simple.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview#java

Comment: Click on the link and see an example